# Tree Routing in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a problem about tree routing in Zend Framework 2, I hope you'll help me.

I'm building module Administrator. When I login, it will run loginAction of AdministratorController. When I login success, it will go to indexAction of AdministratorController. I'm done this.

zf2exam.loc/Administrator ---> login --> login success -> zf2exam.loc/Administrator/index.php

So, when I login success, I want to manage all controllers of module Administrator. How must I do to route to another controller in module Administrator? Example: zf2exam.loc/Administrator/News/Update/1. Thanks for your watching. Thanks so much.

```
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Admin\Controller\Admin' => 'Admin\Controller\AdminController',
        'Admin\Controller\News' => 'Admin\Controller\NewsController',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/admin[/:action][/:id]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'admin',
                    'action' => 'login',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'about',
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'doctype' => 'HTML5',
        'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test, but i would do something like this :

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'type' => 'Litteral',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/Administrator',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Admin',
                    'action' => 'login',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/:controller[/:action[/:id]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                            'id' => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Admin',
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```